# CSS style not applying as expected (Haskell project)

Tags: css, haskell

I have this code:

```
elAttr "h1" ("class" =: "content") $ text "Welcome to the app!"
```

Which is supposed to reference this style:

```
.content h1 {
 font-size: 2em;
 margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

But the h1 style is not being applied.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Here is how my HTML is rendered:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us how your html is rendered ?

Comment: @JithinB - Good point.  I have added a screenshot above.

Answer (score 2):

Is that showing like,

```
<h1 class="content">Welcome to the app!</h1>
```

If it is like this above example, try this

```
h1.content{
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

or just .content

Comment: Thanks.  I will testing this.  But the CSS comes from a stylesheet / library that I do not want to edit.  I am trying to understand how to change the Haskell.

Comment: @LevelChart8 the original css applies to h1 elements inside and element with class="content". So you should probably have a div around everything with with the class set instead of having the class set on the h1 element

Comment: @ShamPooSham Thank you.  That makes sense.  Now, I only have to discover how to wrap everything in a div with Obelisk/Haskell.  EDIT: I figured it out!